# Missing required argument $adapters of Magento\Search\Model\AdapterFactory

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

This error is showing up on a clean installation of Magento 2. I've tried to re-install a clean Magento 2 version on another domain and it's giving me the same problems.

To replicate:

1. Get a domain.
2. Login SSH.
3. Run command `/usr/local/bin/composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation-folder-here>`
4. Enter that folder and run `bin/magento setup:install \ --base-url=http://domain.com \ --db-host=localhost \ --db-name=database_name \ --db-user=database_user \ --db-password=database_pass \ --admin-firstname=Name \ --admin-lastname=LastName \ --admin-email=test@test.com \ --admin-user=Admin \ --admin-password=test \ --language=en_US \ --currency=EUR \ --timezone=America/Chicago \ --use-rewrites=1`.
5. Halfway through the installation, I get the message that it can't connect to "Elesticsearch", so I run this code to disable it `bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}`.
6. Re-run step 4.
7. Refresh the cache/index and run the magento setup:upgrade + setup:static-content:deploy. `-f bin/magento cache:clean -f bin/magento cache:flush -f bin/magento setup:upgrade -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`.
8. log in to the back-end and create a category.
9. Go to the front-end, open the category and now you're greeted by the error message (http://prntscr.com/v74ane).

Am I doing something wrong? Isn't this way of installing Magento 2 supposed to download everything straight from Magento 2 themselves? Also if this is relevant information, it downloads/installs Magento 2.4.1.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo service elasticsearch restart` if this running correctly,
then check your module `php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7`

this errow will resolve.

this error is related to ElasticSearch as magento 2.4 need elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue for me was resolved by this steps:

- re-enable ElasticSearch Magento modules after initial setup. Without setup:upgrade command;
- put params of working ElasticSearch service in Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search;
- rebuild project and clean all cache.

As I know, Catalog of newest Magento can`t work without ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mac BigSur with Magento 2.4.2.

Based on [Ali Raza](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/332090/82325) answer to make it work, I needed to follow these steps and run the commands below:

1. `elasticsearch -d` to start the Elasticsearch in the background.
2. `php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7` to re-enable the Elasticsearch that I disabled to install Magento.

*P.S.:* You must install the [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html) if you don't have it on your mac. And you can do it using homebrew.

3. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
4. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
5. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
6. `php bin/magento cache:flush`

*P.S.: If you have any memory issue as I had, you can use `-dmemory_limit=3G` between PHP and bin/magento when running the commands.*